# Angular2 request and response to be signed using RSA key

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a forgot password form and i am calling the HTTP service in the following way,

```
let hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(formdata.newpassword);
      let newPassBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
      let url = this.UPIService+'/resetpassword?mobileNo='+this.shareService.getDeviceDetails().mobile;
      console.log('url---'+url);
      let input_data = JSON.stringify({"password": newPassBase64});
      return this.putMethod(url, input_data);
```

Here any body can change the mobile number and they can update the password of some other person.

Is there any way to secure using SHA256withRSA?

- Signing algorithms SHA256withRSA
- Using private key, Sign the request.
- Using public key, verify the request.

**we have installed SSL certificate in the server level but not in the app level**.( is it required to install in app level also?)

Comment: Do you have any new information about this?